# How to replace a pattern containing '$' in a string in Spark Sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a string  "$urlhjkj" and 
I wish to replace the "$url" part of it with "ssss"
Tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
spark.sql(s"""select regexp_replace("$$urlhjkj","$$url","ssss") """).first(){0}
```

I even tried:

```
 spark.sql(s"""select regexp_replace("$$urlhjkj","\\u0024url","ssss") """).first(){0}
```

But this too doesn't work.

What am I missing?
In hive the following works perfectly:

```
select regexp_replace("$urlhjkj","\\u0024url","ssss")
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument in the [regex_replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#regexp_replace(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) function is a column. So you must pass the column name, not a literal string. The below code works fine in spark.

```
df.withColumn("test1", lit("$$urlhjkj"))
  .withColumn("test", regexp_replace(col("test1"), "\\$\\$url", "ssss"))
```

Below are the results.

`|test1    |test    |
+---------+--------+
|$$urlhjkj|sssshjkj|
|$$urlhjkj|sssshjkj|
|$$urlhjkj|sssshjkj|`

Comment: spark.sql(s"""select regexp_replace("#urlhjkj","#url","ssss") """).first(){0} This works. Its about the $ replacement.

Comment: Please use the below code.

spark.sql("""select regexp_replace("$$urlhjkj","\\$\\$url","ssss") """).first(){0}

When you use 's' prefix in spark.sql(), $ is used for local variables and hence is reserved.

Answer (score 0):

> regexp_replace(str, regexp, rep) - Replaces all substrings of str that match regexp with rep.

Str should be a column of type string.